# Смена сцен JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

Добрый вечер народ, у меня тут сцены менять не получается. Не могу понять где ошибка. Не подскажете?

```
public class CanvasEx extends Application {
final int size=1000, dot_size=10, up=1, right=2, down=3, left=4, w=1, d=2, s=3, a=4;
int delay=100, length=2, dir=2, food_x, food_y, length_2=2, dir_2=2;
Canvas canvas;
GraphicsContext gc;
int x[]=new int[size*size];
int y[]=new int[size*size];
int x_2[]=new int[size*size];
int y_2[]=new int[size*size];
Thread game;
Stage st;
Scene scene, scene2, scene3;
Button b3, b2, b1;
boolean lost=false;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Stage st;
    st=primaryStage;
    FlowPane root1 = new FlowPane();
    FlowPane root2 = new FlowPane();
    FlowPane root3 = new FlowPane();
    root1.setVgap(10);
    root1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: tan;-fx-padding: 10px;");
    root2.setVgap(10);
    root2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: tan;-fx-padding: 10px;");
    root3.setVgap(10);
    root3.setStyle("-fx-background-color: tan;-fx-padding: 10px;");
    canvas=new Canvas(size,size);
    gc=canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    canvas.setFocusTraversable(true);
    root1.getChildren().add(canvas);
    startGame();
    canvas.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
            KeyCode key=e.getCode();
            if(key.equals(KeyCode.UP) && dir!=down) dir=up;
            if(key.equals(KeyCode.DOWN) && dir!=up) dir=down;
            if(key.equals(KeyCode.LEFT) && dir!=right) dir=left;
            if(key.equals(KeyCode.RIGHT) && dir!=left) dir=right;
            if(key.equals(KeyCode.W) && dir_2!=s) dir_2=w;
            if(key.equals(KeyCode.S) && dir_2!=w) dir_2=s;
            if(key.equals(KeyCode.A) && dir_2!=d) dir_2=a;
            if(key.equals(KeyCode.D) && dir_2!=a) dir_2=d;
        }

    });
    Scene scene = new Scene(root1, size, size);
    Scene scene2 = new Scene(root2, size, size);
    Scene scene3 = new Scene(root3, size, size);
    Label l1=new Label("SNAKE GAME");
    Button b3=new Button("Restart");
    Button b2=new Button("Main Menu");
    Button b1=new Button("Start Game");
    b1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            control(t);
        }
    });
    b2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            control(t);
        }
    });
    b3.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            control(t);
        }
    });
    root3.getChildren().add(b3);
    root3.getChildren().add(b2);
    root2.getChildren().add(l1);
    root2.getChildren().add(b1);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene2);
    primaryStage.show();
}
public void draw(GraphicsContext gc){
    gc.clearRect(0, 0, size, size);
    if(!lost){

        //gc.setFill(Paint.valueOf("green"));
        //gc.fillOval(food_x, food_y, dot_size, dot_size);
        gc.setFill(Paint.valueOf("brown"));
        gc.fillOval(x[0], y[0], dot_size, dot_size);
        gc.setFill(Paint.valueOf("red"));
        for(int i=1; i<length; i++){
            gc.fillOval(x[i], y[i], dot_size, dot_size);
        }
        gc.setFill(Paint.valueOf("black"));
        gc.fillOval(x_2[0], y_2[0], dot_size, dot_size);
        gc.setFill(Paint.valueOf("blue"));
        for(int i=1; i<length_2; i++){
            gc.fillOval(x_2[i], y_2[i], dot_size, dot_size);
        }

    }else{
        gc.setFill(Paint.valueOf("black"));
        gc.fillText("Game Over", size/2-50, size/2-15);
        st.setScene(scene3);

        game.stop();
    }
}
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
public void control(ActionEvent t) {
    if (t.getSource()==b1)
        st.setScene(scene);
    if (t.getSource()==b3)
        st.setScene(scene);
    else if(t.getSource()==b2)
        st.setScene(scene2);
}
private void startGame() {
    length=2;
    length_2=2;
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
        x[i]=50-i*dot_size;
        y[i]=50;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<length_2; i++){
        x[i]=500-i*dot_size;
        y[i]=500;
    }
    //locateFood();
    game=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                if(!lost){
                    //checkFood();
                    checkCollision();
                    move();
                    length++;
                    length_2++;
                }
                draw(gc);
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(delay);
                } catch(Exception e){};
            }
        }
    });
    game.start();
}

private void locateFood() {
    food_x=(int)(Math.random()*((size/dot_size)-1))*dot_size;
    food_y=(int)(Math.random()*((size/dot_size)-1))*dot_size;
}
private void checkFood() {
    if(x[0]==food_x && y[0]==food_y){
        length++;
        locateFood();
    }
    if(x_2[0]==food_x && y_2[0]==food_y){
        length_2++;
        locateFood();
    }
}
private void checkCollision() {
    if(x[0]>=size || y[0]>=size) lost=true;
    if(x[0]<0 || y[0]<0) lost=true;
    if(x_2[0]>=size || y_2[0]>=size) lost=true;
    if(x_2[0]<0 || y_2[0]<0) lost=true;

    for(int i=2; i<length; i++)
        if(x[0]==x[i] && y[0]==y[i]) lost=true;
    for(int i=2; i<length_2; i++)
        if(x_2[0]==x_2[i] && y_2[0]==y_2[i]) lost=true;
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
        if(x[0]==x_2[i] && y[0]==y_2[i]) lost=true;
    for(int i=0; i<length_2; i++)
        if(x_2[0]==x[i] && y_2[0]==y[i]) lost=true;
}
private void move() {
    for(int i=length-1;i>0;i--){
        x[i]=x[i-1];
        y[i]=y[i-1];

    }
    for(int i=length_2-1;i>0;i--){
        x_2[i]=x_2[i-1];
        y_2[i]=y_2[i-1];
    }
    if(dir==up)y[0]-=dot_size;
    if(dir==down)y[0]+=dot_size;
    if(dir==right)x[0]+=dot_size;
    if(dir==left)x[0]-=dot_size;
    if(dir_2==w)y_2[0]-=dot_size;
    if(dir_2==s)y_2[0]+=dot_size;
    if(dir_2==d)x_2[0]+=dot_size;
    if(dir_2==a)x_2[0]-=dot_size;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Честно сказать я как то не заметил в Вашем примере попытки изменить сцену.Но как прямой ответ вот пример кода смены сцен в рамках одних подмостков:

```
public class Test extends Application {
    private Scene first;
    private Scene second;
    private Stage primaryStage;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        first = new Scene(new Group(addEvent(new Button("first"))), 300, 300);
        second = new Scene(new Group(addEvent(new Button("second"))), 300, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(first);
        (this.primaryStage = primaryStage).show();
    }

    private Button addEvent(Button b) {
        b.setOnMouseClicked((e) -> {
            primaryStage.setScene(((Button) e.getSource()).getText() == "first" ? second : first);
        });
        return b;
    }

}
```

и в добавок прислушайтесь к комментарию @GVArt: с потоками в JavaFx не все так просто к примеру добавление объекта в основной поток происходит через вызов статического метода у класса Platform:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //TODO something
    }
});
```

}

который было-бы неплохо обернуть в `Task`

Answer (score 0):

Мало вероятно что у вас это получиться. Перепишите ваш метод Control. Используйте только одну сцену и один FlowPane. А все Node добовляйте по новой в FlowPane.

```
root.getChildrens().removeAll();
root.getChilderns().addAll(YOUR_ELEMENTS_THERE);
```

Объекты не пересоздовайте( если этого не требует логика) что бы не тратить зря ресурсы.
Таким образом вы удалите все элементы из окна и добавите новые которые вам нужны.

Comment: ПС. не используйте потоки (Thread) в JavaFX они не предназначены для этого. В JavaFX есть класс для работы concurrency (Task) https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html